# How to parse data effectively

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I've a data coming from api which is in the form

```
"A,B,C,D,E\n

17945,10091,10088,3907,10132\n

2,12,13,48,11"
```

in the above form.

The meaning of data is A is mapped to 17945 and 2 (A->17945->2) similarly for others. I want to save this data on my model array

```
struct DataModel {
        var name : String
        var id1 : String
        var id2 : String            
    }
```

The question is how do I do this effectively.

What Im thinking is splitting the the data from api , creating arrays respectively and initialising the data model accordingly, but is there a another way to do this using dictionaries , it is not neccassary to use model here , I just need all the respective data in one go.

Comment: The word data is a plural form of the word datum.  There is no English word you have spelled datas.  The word above is not an adjective.

Comment: @ElTomato I corrected it, Arigatō.:p

Comment: It would be more efficient if the API was sending well-structured data.

Comment: @vadian already discussed with team , it would take 15 days to process the request here , and then too it is not sure that the request will be approved at backend team , so yeah Im stuck !

Comment: You can split each row in a separate string (split by \n), then create 3 different arrays from the 3 strings separated by comma, then iterate from 0 to array count and in each iteration create your DataModel object using those 3 arrays and the current index. This is obviously not a good solution but should work as a workaround just in case you have no other ideas.

Comment: @SavcaMarin Im already using this workaround :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if you want to create data from this raw data, you can do as like below

```
let names = ["A","B","C","D","E"]

let element2 = [17945,10091,10088,3907,10132]

let element3 = [2,12,13,48,11]

struct DataModel {
    var name : String
    var id1 : String
    var id2 : String
}

var allElements: [DataModel] = []

for i in zip(names, zip(element2, element3)) {
    let model = DataModel(name: i.0, id1: i.1.0.description, id2: i.1.1.description)
    allElements.append(model)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is what you need, but one of the variants how to

```
struct DataModel {

var name: String
var id1: String
var id2: String

public init(n: String, i1: String, i2: String) {
    name = n
    id1 = i1
    id2 = i2
}
```

}

```
let numberOfArrays = string.components(separatedBy: "\n").count
let aString = string.replacingOccurrences(of: "\n", with: ",").components(separatedBy: ",")
let step = aString.count / numberOfArrays
for i in 0..<step {
    allElements.append(DataModel(n: aString[i], i1: aString[i + step], i2: aString[i + step * 2]))
}
```

UPDATE:

here is else one more variant with dictionary result

```
private func parse() {
    var dictionary: [Int: String] = [:]
    _ = inputString
        .components(separatedBy: "\n")
        .compactMap { $0.components(separatedBy: ",") }
        .compactMap { arr in
            arr
                .enumerated()
                .compactMap { index, element in
                    var str = dictionary[index] ?? ""
                    str += element
                    dictionary[index] = str
            }
    }
}
```

where dictionary.values() will be desired elements

Comment: during my code review this is not passed :P, they are saying this is not efficient enough, as I have to sort the data also name wise , hence I've to change this after making the datamodels what I'm doing is sorting the data name wise and changing some values in it and then sending back the data in same form as it came, let me know if you can help if something more efficient pop's up :p.

Comment: okay, input is your string, you do some modifications, and post new string, right? but how do you understand which model should be changed? if there are some rules, you can use replace with regex

Comment: Im just sorting the data model and doing some simple O(1) operations , after that I'm making the string to return , all the manipulations , like making the string again is O(N) in worst case. So that's why I was thinking if there is something we can do where we are making DataModel, can we get the data without using the datamodel(I mean in one place) so that I can apply basic sorting like operations to it.

Comment: you can use dictionary instead of DataModel